# ProfileController@store is not send post method and not save any data to profile table

Tags: php, laravel

I am new with PHP and Laravel.
I am using Laravel Framework version 5.3.29 and PHP 7

I am making extend register form with two parts.
register form which makes login credentials; Username and password
and after login credentials has been created, second part is creating profile to new user.

Process: Register form save data to user table and use user model.
after succesfully created username & password, it will redirect to
profile form and send post data to proceed form and validation.

Profile form is using profile model.

1) how to troubleshoot, when data has been sent by post method and n there is no error message. it only return back to profile form after submit button has been pressed.

2) I can see there is no data save to profile table.

register (user table) and profile table are in same database as
 register form can save it, database part works fine.

code skeleton has made from "php artisan make:auth
complete code can be found https://github.com/mikromika/project1/

my route file is following:

```
// Registration Routes
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

// Show profile form
Route::get('bio/create', ['as' => 'bio.create', 'uses' => 'Bio\ProfileController@create']);

Route::post('bio/store', ['as' => 'bio.store', 'uses' => 'Bio\ProfileController@store']);
```

ProfileController:store
this should validate data and save it to profile table

```
        public function store(Request $request)

    {    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
        $this->guard()->login($this->createx($request->all()));
       Session::flash('success', 'Data was successfully save!');

       if ($exception instanceof TokenMismatchException) {
         Session::flash('success', 'Data was failed to save!');
                return redirect('/auth/login');
       }

  //  show profile form info after success post; does not work yet
return redirect()->route('bio.show');  }
```

Here is profile form way to send post method.

```
<form id="profile-form"  action="{{ url('/bio/store')  }}" method="POST" form class="form-horizontal">
      {{ csrf_field() }}
```

post method is never reach that ProfileController:store part.

I have tried to use "GET" method, but I'm getting error

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:
```

I have changed route to

```
Route::get('bio/store', ['as' => 'bio.store', 'uses' => 'Bio\ProfileController@store']);
```

and  form   `<form id="profile-form"  action="{{ url('/bio/store')  }}" method="GET" form class="form-horizontal">`

Because form need to send by "POST" method, I understand that error!.

Here is validate part from ProfileController:validator

```
protected function validator(array $data)    // copied from register controller
  {
      return Validator::make($data, [

        'firstname'         => 'required|max:255',
        'lastname '         => 'required|max:255',
        'email'             => 'required|email|max:255|unique',
        'phone'             => 'integer',
        'mobile'            => 'integer',

      ]);
  }
```

Here is ProfileController:createx part 
I took it from registerController.

```
protected function createx(array $data)    //copied from register controller
  {                                          // was dublicate name "create"
      return Profile::createx([              // changed to "createx"
          'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
          'lastname' => $data['lastname'],


     ]);
  }
```

Here is profile model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Profile extends Model
{
    //
      protected $table = 'profiles';
      protected $fillable = [
          'firstname',
           'lastname',
           'email',
           'phone',
           'mobile',
            // 'name', 'email', 'password',
      ];


      protected $hidden = [
          'status',
          //'location',
      ];
}
```

Thanks to Alexey Mezenin DD() tip for troubleshoot

> @MikroMika this data shows that you do not pass firstname and
>   lastname. Look at result of the dd($data); It should be something like
>   ['firstname' => 'John', 'lastname' => 'Smith'] – Alexey Mezenin 20
>   mins ago

Now I am back to beginning,

Why form is not pass data by POST method ?

Comment: found other way to test POST method;

in route file web.php (L5.3) 

` Route::post('posttest', function(){
          return 'post is working'; }); `

this example  gives error : 
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:

Answer (score 1):

There is no `createx()` method in Eloquent. You defined it in a controller, but you're trying to use it with the model. Use `create()` method:

```
return Profile::create([
    'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
    'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
]);
```

Also, you've asked how to troubleshoot. Install Laravel Debugbar. Also, using [`dd()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-dd) helper is really helpful:

```
dd(Profile::create([
    'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
    'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
]));
```

Comment: Thanks for troubleshoot tip.

inside ProfileController
public function store(Request $request)

I am using 
 ' dd(validator::validate([
    'firstname' => $request['firstname'],
    'lastname' => $request['lastname'],
      ])); '

Comment: Gave me one step forward, error msg ,-D: 
Type error: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Validation\Factory::validate() must be of the type array, none given,

Comment: other test '  dd(Profile::create([
      'firstname' => $request['firstname'],
      'lastname' => $request['lastname'],
  ])); '

 #table: "profiles"
  #fillable: array:5 [▼
    0 => "firstname"
    1 => "lastname"
    2 => "email"
    3 => "phone"
    4 => "mobile"

 #attributes: array:5 [▼
    "firstname" => null
    "lastname" => null
    "updated_at" => "2017-01-26 10:33:31"
    "created_at" => "2017-01-26 10:33:31"
    "id" => 1
  ]

Comment: 'code'  #original: array:5 [▼
    "firstname" => null
    "lastname" => null
    "updated_at" => "2017-01-26 10:33:31"
    "created_at" => "2017-01-26 10:33:31"
    "id" => 1
  ] 'code'

Thanks first time I can see it what I already expected.

Firstname and lastname are null!

Comment: @MikroMika this data shows that you do not pass `firstname` and `lastname`. Look at result of the `dd($data);` It should be something like `['firstname' => 'John', 'lastname' => 'Smith']`